# XSL tracking'blind-spots' by line number in muti-pass xslt

Tags: xslt, xalan

A previous similar-looking question to mine is: "tracing-source-elements-through-multiple-xsl-transforms", but I'm seeking a **way** to trace xsl/xml file line numbers for failed/successful compiles and the like. I have multiple passes restricted by template "modes". In the meantime I can ask for help in the source of the problem:

In the multi-pass XSL, Pass1 transforms MSWord(2003)tags using file 'XSLT1' which includes file 'XSLT2' which does Pass 2 concatenating split nodes thereof, and now the intention in Pass3 (which is within XSLT2 - owing to file include problems) is to group/rearrange the 'clean' xml into SQL DDL, but nothing is being recognised in pass3.

Incidentally, I'm trying this through - **NetBeansIDE (8.0.2)** com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.EqualityExpr
*"Which simply states on console:* for example on compile error: 
 cannot be cast to com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Pattern - NO FILE/LINE NUMBER CONTEXT- This transform has multiple files and at least three passes of which pass3 seems to be my current problem.
Now for the detail -  After two passes, I have seemingly well-formed intermediate xml that I want to process further: (The intermediate xml leads with 'Document/Body/Section/Segment' in actual xml file).

Incidentally, pass2 output below alludes to a DB Table name in first Segment, with a Table qualifier after, then Column names in the first Column segment, and Row values in the remainder of Segments:

```
<Document>
<Body>
<Section>
<Segment frags="1" size="32">
<Entry ycoord="1.40" xcoord="1.1" size="32" frags="1" desgn="Table">TEACHING AND LEARNING EXPERIENCE</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="1" size="25">
<Entry ycoord="2.40" xcoord="1.1" frags="1" size="25" desgn="Table">UNIVERSITY MODULES TAUGHT</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment>
<Entry ycoord="3.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">Module(Full title and code – not abbreviated)</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="3.40" xcoord="2.6" desgn="Column">Level(Indicate year level, if graduate module, otherwise Honours or Masters)</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="3.40" xcoord="3.6" desgn="Column">University</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="3.40" xcoord="4.6" desgn="Column">From(mm/yyyy)</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="3.40" xcoord="5.6" desgn="Column">To(mm/yyyy)</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="3.40" xcoord="6.6" desgn="Column">Total period</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="7" size="87">
<Entry ycoord="4.40" xcoord="1.6 desgn="Column">Transport planning 201</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="4.40" xcoord="2.6" desgn="Column">Undergraduate</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="4.40" xcoord="3.6" desgn="Column">University of LLL</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="4.40" xcoord="4.6" desgn="Column">January 2011</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="4.40" xcoord="5.6" desgn="Column">-</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="4.40" xcoord="6.6" desgn="Column">3 years &amp; 2Months</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="6" size="98">
<Entry ycoord="5.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">RI Planning 202</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="5.40" xcoord="2.6" desgn="Column">Undergraduate</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="5.40" xcoord="3.6" desgn="Column">University of LLL</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="5.40" xcoord="4.6" desgn="Column">January 2011</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="5.40" xcoord="5.6" desgn="Column">December 2012</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="5.40" xcoord="6.6" desgn="Column">2 years</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="6" size="96">
<Entry ycoord="6.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">LG and Civil Society</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="6.40" xcoord="2.6" desgn="Column">Undergraduate</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="6.40" xcoord="3.6" desgn="Column">University of LLL</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="6.40" xcoord="4.6" desgn="Column">July 2010</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="6.40" xcoord="5.6" desgn="Column">-</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="6.40" xcoord="6.6" desgn="Column">3 years &amp; 7 Months</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="6" size="101">
<Entry ycoord="7.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">LGCS 242</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="7.40" xcoord="2.6" desgn="Column">UG/Entry>
<Entry ycoord="7.40" xcoord="3.6" desgn="Column">University of LLL</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="7.40" xcoord="4.6" desgn="Column">July 2010</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="7.40" xcoord="5.6" desgn="Column">December 2013</Entry>
<Entry ycoord="7.40" xcoord="6.6" desgn="Column">3 years</Entry>
</Segment>
</Section>
</Body>
</Document>
```

```
<xsl:transfrorm>
<xsl:template match="/" mode="pass2">
    <xsl:variable name="pass2Out">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="pass2"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="pass2Node" select="exslt:node-set($pass2Out)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pass2Node/*" mode="pass3"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:transform>
```

```
<xsl:transform>
<!-- ... -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="pass3">
    <xsl:copy>
       <!-- have tried numerous other patterns to match here -->
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass3" select="Document/Body/Section/Segment/Entry"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- one of many failed attempts at transforming pass2 output -->
<xsl:template match="Entry" mode="pass3">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="@desgn"/>       
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The outcomes of the above pass3 transformation attempts are untouched; despite additional hooks perhaps equally flawed and not listed here. PASS 3 misses EVERYTHING, and the pass3 output remains exactly as above. How can one find out where the templates/modes/matches are flawed or missed?

Alternatively, If one can show how to match the implied DB entity names contained in the xml element text, for purpose of generating appropriate DDL clauses, the first missed-match question would for me be moot.

Comment: I have no clue what your question is. "*I'm seeking a way to trace xsl/xml file line numbers for failed/successful compiles*" Normally, if there's an **error** in parsing the XML file or in processing it through the XSLT, the processor will give you an error message indicating the problematic code by (at least) the line number. However, the processor is not a mind reader: if your templates do not match the source XML, no error will be thrown.

Comment: Just to respond on the initial part of my vague/confused question, I was hoping there was a way for tracing the progress of the translator a-la JavaCC for example, where one could trace 'scanner' hits or more detailed 'parser' hits. I cannot seem to find a similar utility in this. It would have helped one find out novice miscues in precedence, priority, axis , etc (I think); **run-time** source, in addition to the pre-run-time compile errors **xls**.

Comment: Just to respond on the initial part of my vague/confused question, I was hoping there was a way for tracing the progress of the translator a-la JavaCC for example, where one could trace 'scanner' hits or more detailed 'parser' hits. I cannot seem to find a similar utilty in this. It would have helped one find out novice miscues in precedence, priority, axis , etc (I think); run-time, in addition to the pre-run-time compile errors.

Comment: It seems that the xsl:include of Identity pattern stylesheets cannot be repeated beyond one include. The intervening passes have to be of non-identity if the parser is to work as expected. I close my question on this observation.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to transform the above (after fixing typos in lies 20 and 50) missing " and missing < respectively, using the following, but not as an included file (original problem):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl exslt w aml wpc dt mc o v w10 wx wne wsp sl">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/" mode="pass3">
    <xsl:variable name="pass3Out">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="pass3"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="pass3Node" select="exslt:node-set($pass3Out)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pass3Node/*" mode="pass4"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Document" mode="pass3"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Document" mode="pass3">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Meta" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Body/Logo" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Body/Prelim" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Body/Section" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Meta" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body/Logo" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Segment" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Entry[not(@ycoord = preceding-sibling::Entry/@ycoord)]">
            <xsl:variable name="Coord" select="@ycoord"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="../Entry[@ycoord = $Coord]">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

AND OBTAINED:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
<Segment frags="1" size="32">
<Entry ycoord="1.40" xcoord="1.1" size="32" frags="1" desgn="Table">"TEACHING AND LEARNING EXPERIENCE"</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="1" size="25">
<Entry ycoord="2.40" xcoord="1.1" frags="1" size="25" desgn="Table">"UNIVERSITY MODULES TAUGHT"</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment>
<Entry ycoord="3.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">"Module(Full title and code – not abbreviated)""Level(Indicate year level, if graduate module, otherwise Honours or Masters)""University""From(mm/yyyy)""To(mm/yyyy)""Total period"</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="7" size="87">
<Entry ycoord="4.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">"Transport planning 201""Undergraduate""University of LLL""January 2011""-""3 years &amp; 2Months"</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="6" size="98">
<Entry ycoord="5.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">"RI Planning 202""Undergraduate""University of LLL""January 2011""December 2012""2 years"</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="6" size="96">
<Entry ycoord="6.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">"LG and Civil Society""Undergraduate""University of LLL""July 2010""-""3 years &amp; 7 Months"</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment frags="6" size="101">
<Entry ycoord="7.40" xcoord="1.6" desgn="Column">"LGCS 242""UG""University of LLL""July 2010""December 2013""3 years"</Entry>
</Segment>
</Document>
```

NEXT HURDLE:
I need to alter the  attribute to say  after the first Column Names row.
Here's what I've been struggling with in pass4 of the document (I omit the Identity design preamble):

```
<xsl:template match="Segment" mode="pass4">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Entry[@desgn='Column'] and preceding-sibling::Entry[@desgn = 'Table']">
               <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*/Entry[@desgn = 'Column']">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="@ycoord" /><xsl:copy-of select="@xcoord" />
                  <xsl:attribute name="desgn">RowVals</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Which strips everything but text() instead of applying a simple substitution of 'Column' with 'RowVals'. Any help is appreciated.